# Optimistic concurrency using _primary_term, _seq_no in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Elasticsearch added _primary_term, _seq_no as new mechanism for optimistic concurrency. Are there plans to support _primary_term, _seq_no in spring-data-elasticsearch module?

Comment: I'm also interested in this, since the support for `VersionType.INTERNAL` and the `@Version` annotation seems to have been dropped in ES7. I can't find anything in the documentation for the upcoming 4.0.0 version how this is supposed to work...